# async setter в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, setter

есть ли такая возможность в js сделась обычный сеттер async-нутым ?

```
class SomeClass{
    set async someSetter(value){
        await ...;
        await ...;
        await ...;
    }
}


await someInstance.someSetter= value; //должно скомпилироваться как await someInstance.semeSetter(value)
```

Comment: А что нужно получить на выходе, что должен делать этот код?

Comment: Наверное стоит начать с того, что этой возможности нет в стандарте, так что искать её решение как-то... странно.

Comment: _должно скомпилироваться_ - чем это должно скомпилироваться?

Comment: @Grandy должно скомпилироваться babel-ом

Comment: @vnn198 сеттер делает некоторые асинхронные операции с БД